# (rails) После сохранения svg изображение сжимается (геометрические параметры)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg

```
def svg_save
svg_string = "
      <svg class='filterPlace' height='#{self.image_height}' width='#{self.image_width}'>
        <defs>
              <filter id='fp1'>
                <feComponentTransfer>
                  <feFuncR id='filter_r' slope='#{r_component}' type='linear'></feFuncR>
                  <feFuncG id='filter_g' slope='#{g_component}' type='linear'></feFuncG>
                  <feFuncB id='filter_b' slope='#{b_component}' type='linear'></feFuncB>
                  <feFuncA type='identity'></feFuncA>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feColorMatrix id='filter_saturate' type='saturate' values='#{saturate}'></feColorMatrix>
              </filter>
        </defs>
        <image class='svg_place_image' filter='url(#fp1)' height='#{self.image_height}' width='#{self.image_width}' xlink:href='#{self.image.path}'></image>
      </svg>"
img = Magick::Image.from_blob(svg_string){
  self.format = 'SVG'
}
file = Tempfile.new(['image', '.png'])
img[0].write(file.path)
self.update_attribute(:image, file)
file.close
file.unlink
end
```

Просто создаю изображение c фильтрами с заранее раcсчитанными высотой и шириной. После сохранения в `file` почему-то меньшие размеры чем в указанных `self.image_height` и `self.image_width`. Есть идеи?

Comment: Есть. Возьмите отладчик, зацепитесь прямо перед записью, и проверьте, откуда там такие числа.

Comment: Числа отлаживал. Рэйзил и img прям после from_blob - выдавал уже искажённый размер. Пробовал вместо <image> <circle> написать - всё работает как нужно.

Comment: `raise Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(Paperclip.io_adapters.for(self.image)).height.inspect` в начале метода выдаёт 130 (например). `raise Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(Paperclip.io_adapters.for(file)).height.inspect` после записи может 100 выдать.

Comment: То есть, вы точно убедились, что `self.image_height` и `self.image_width` (где `self`, кстати, избыточен) правильные? Приведите конкретные цифры для примера, чтобы было проще искать причину. С размерами исходных изображений. Или даже несколько наборов.

Comment: До модуля - image_height: 475, image_width: 460
После модуля - image_height: 380, image_width: 369
если дальше прогонять эту картинку
image_height: 306, image_width: 296
image_height: 247, image_width: 238

Comment: Ещё если жёстко устанавливать в svg height и width, то также сжимает. Если у картинки поставить 125% высоту и ширину, то изображение не искажается, а холст обрезается.

Comment: Выходит, что сжимает на 25% высоту и ширину

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick искажал картинку при конвертировании видимо. Нашёл [вот что](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853325/how-to-convert-a-svg-to-a-png-with-image-magick). Inkscape отлично решил проблему. `inkscape -z -e out.png input.svg`.

```
  def svg_save
    svg_string = "
          <svg height='#{self.image_height}' width='#{self.image_width}'>
            <defs>
                  <filter id='fp1'>
                    <feComponentTransfer>
                      <feFuncR slope='#{r_component}' type='linear'></feFuncR>
                      <feFuncG slope='#{g_component}' type='linear'></feFuncG>
                      <feFuncB slope='#{b_component}' type='linear'></feFuncB>
                      <feFuncA type='identity'></feFuncA>
                    </feComponentTransfer>
                    <feColorMatrix type='saturate' values='#{saturate}'></feColorMatrix>
                  </filter>
            </defs>
            <image filter='url(#fp1)' height='100%' width='100%' xlink:href='#{self.image.path}'></image>
          </svg>"
    file = File.new('svg_temp.svg', 'w+')
    File.write(file, svg_string)
    system("inkscape -z -e #{self.image.path} #{file.path}")
    file.close
    File.delete(file)
  end
```

Comment: Первый раз публикую. В ответе код как-то некрасиво встал.

Comment: Перед каждой строкой кода должно быть 4 пробела, а вокруг блока по пустой строке. Или, если их нет, можно выделить код и нажать Ctrl+K. У вас было по 2 пробела, я сделал Ctrl+K, стало 6. Ну, в любом случае лучше, чем было :]